# Text inside a div / spacing and formatting issue

Tags: css, html, spacing

Is there a way to make the lines in my example to be with less spacing between them?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I see the result, there is a lot of space between the "test" lines.

Thanks,

Marco,

Comment: Browsers have a default "user-agent stylesheet" which applies default styling to various HTML elements. `<p>` elements by default have vertical margins on them to hold them apart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spacing can be caused by a few different things. Most notably, line-height, margins and padding associated with your `<p>` tags.

They can all be adjusted using CSS:

```
p {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 0.2em 0;
}
```

There's lots of experimenting that can be done here, and plenty of help on google for more details on how CSS can effect things.

Answer (score 2):

With CSS, just add this line in your style section:

```
​p { margin-bottom: -.2em; }​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fm7LC/) here

Answer (score 2):

```
​p{
    line-height: 16px;
}​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3cCJX/